# when button pressed the msg shoud proceed in console

Tags: cocoa, xcode

hi i'm new to this. trainee in berazee looking for the code i assigned the value to call an object,while the button is pressed some msg should be printed in the console

Answer (score 0):

You can log to the console with NSLog.

```
NSLog(@"text to be logged");
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@",myObject);
```

Comment: how to loop the button dude how to call the function

Comment: Create an IBAction. If you don't know how to do this, i recommend buying a book or finding some good tutorials online to learn Cocoa/Xcode.